# Can a go module have no go.mod file?

Tags: go, go-modules

I ran into a repo that seems to be a Go module, but there's no `go.mod` file in it: github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.

Is it ok for a go module to have no `go.mod` file with dependencies, or the authors of that library just didn't migrate to modules yet?

Comment: A "module" is a set of "packages" versioned together.

Comment: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/628

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dependency modules [do not need to have explicit `go.mod` files](https://golang.org/ref/mod#non-module-compat).

The “main module” in module mode — that is, the module containing the working directory for the `go` command — must have a `go.mod` file, so that the `go` command can figure out the import paths for the packages within that module (based on its [module path](https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-path)), and so that it has a place to record its dependencies once resolved.

In addition, any modules slotted in using [`replace` directives](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) must have `go.mod` files (in order to reduce confusion due to typos or other errors in replacement paths).

However, in general a module that lacks an explicit `go.mod` file is valid and fine to use. Its effective module path is the path by which it was `require`d, which can be a bit confusing if the same repository ends up in use via multiple paths. Since a module with no `go.mod` file necessarily doesn't specify its own dependencies, consumers of that module will have to fill in those dependencies themselves ([`go mod tidy`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy) will mark them as `// indirect` in the consumer's `go.mod` file).

Comment: Thank you for providing this answer. I would accept your answer as the correct one, but I feel like it lacks references to the official documentation. Moreover, references to the official documentation, provided by @Hymns For Disco, contradict this answer. To me it feels like the official go docs are being loosey-goosey about the specifics of Go modules implementation, cause confusion, require refinement and more rigorous approach.

Comment: I have updated the answer to link to the relevant sections of the Go Modules Reference document. FWIW, I don't think any of this contradicts the documentation linked in the other answer: a module “is a collection of packages that are released, versioned, and distributed together”, and it is identified by a module path, but those properties don't necessarily require the presence of an explicit `go.mod` file.

Comment: Thanks, I transferred the accepted answer to this one. The part "A module is defined by a UTF-8 encoded text file named go.mod in its root directory." sounds like `go.mod` is mandatory.

Comment: That's a good point. I've sent https://golang.org/cl/331949 to try to clarify; feel free to comment there if you think it can be improved further!

Answer (score 2):

**SHORT SUMMARY OF THE DISCUSSION:**

The answer is "No"!

This project [contains a set of go packages](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go), but it is not a Go module as it doesn't contain `go.mod` file (although, it [used to be a multi-module repo (Go)](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/commit/1f6f5ba66fd2a6729be5553990c0053b36a076d3) previously).

`go get` can run in both ways: module-aware mode and legacy GOPATH mode (as of Go 1.16).

To read more about this, refer to docs by using the `go` command:

```
$ go help gopath-get
```

and

```
$ go help module-get
```

It'd tell about how `go get` works in both cases.

Also, I noticed that it can download any repository and would treat it as a Go package, even if it contains an arbitrary Python project.

I did a simple test to demonstrate the same:

```
$ go get github.com/mongoengine/mongoengine
```

And it surprisingly worked.

Comment: What a short, clear and useful information to make it clear for non-experts like me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Modules are defined by their go.mod file.  Without a go.mod file, it is not a module.

See this from the [Go Modules Reference](https://golang.org/ref/mod)

> A module is a collection of packages that are released, versioned, and distributed together. Modules may be downloaded directly from version control repositories or from module proxy servers.
>
> A module is identified by a module path, which is declared in a go.mod file, together with information about the module's dependencies. The module root directory is the directory that contains the go.mod file.

And

> A module is defined by a UTF-8 encoded text file named go.mod in its root directory.

Comment: @StevenPenny Aha, so we have a disagreement on terms here, and my question was precisely about it. From the docs I thought it is not a module if it doesn't have a `go.mod` file as @Hymns For Disco suggested. However, when I say `go get github.com\confluentinc\confluent-kafka-go`, go starts building it as if it were a module.

Comment: @BorisBurkov note that modules were introduced in Go much later, in version 1.11, before that you had only *packages* and *programs*. The `go get` command is available since 1.0 (if not earlier), before 1.11 you could only do `go get [package]` (not module, since there weren't any), after 1.11 you can still do `go get [package]` but also `go get [module]`, see [adding dependencies](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them). You'll find many projects on github that do not have a go.mod file but are still go-gettable.

Comment: Before actually establishing the module files, it's ambiguous as to where the module scope may be.  There could be multiple modules within one repository.  You could even have multiple repositories inside the same module (though it would be hard to manage).  It's worth noting that this repository was indeed multiple modules, before the go.mod files were removed. https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/commit/1f6f5ba66fd2a6729be5553990c0053b36a076d3

Comment: @StevenPenny I did a test. I said `go get github.com/BurkovBA/django-rest-framework-mongoengine`, which is a repo with a **python** project. And it worked, `go get` added it to my `go.mod` file as if it were a valid dependency and downloaded the repo into `pkg/mod` modules cache, without checking for `go.mod` file or anything. The documentation says that starting from go 1.16 `go install` is the recommended option for building modules, while `go get` is more about managing downloads: https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-get.

Comment: @BorisBurkov whatever you call it, it is certainly not a *valid* go module.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you, your clarification about the double function of `go get [package/module]` was really helpful. Weird that anything (even a python repo) is treated like a go package by this command.

Comment: @BorisBurkov How's it supposed to differentiate? There's no meta info that tells about that. Also, a repo could have multiple languages — Go, Python, JS, etc, right? If "go get" was made to strictly fetch repos with all `*.go` files only, then it'd be very very big problem. So, it's not at all weird; the behavior is totally correct.

Comment: @xdsarkar Well, as much as I enjoy go's YAGNI minimalistic style, IMHO, this is anarchy. The command line tooling is supposed to require some explicit indication from a repo that it is meant to be used as a go package, something like `package.json` in node.js. `go.mod` file in a top-level directory sound like exactly that.

Comment: Regarding “modules” that contain no Go source files: they are currently treated as valid but are not an intended use-case, and while they may work today they are not explicitly supported (see https://golang.org/issue/31866).